# Uploading multiple files - Rails and React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, file-io

I'm trying to upload multiple files as part of an assignment that a tutor would upload for a student. The student would then be able to click the link and download the files to their computer.

This is what the form looks like where the files are uploaded:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./App";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Form, Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

function AssignWork() {
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { studentId } = location.state;
  const { currentUser, setStudents } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [assignmentData, setAssignmentData] = useState({
    name: "",
    notes: "",
    subject: "",
    tutor_id: currentUser.id,
    student_id: studentId,
    files: "",
  });
  // const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setAssignmentData({ ...assignmentData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  function onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // const formData = new FormData();

    // for (let data in assignmentData) {
    //   formData.append(data, assignmentData[data]);
    // }

    fetch("/assignments", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(assignmentData),
    }).then((resp) => {
      if (resp.ok) {
        resp.json().then((newAssignment) => {
          console.log(newAssignment);
          let studentsList = [
            ...new Map(
              newAssignment.tutor.students.map((student) => [
                student["id"],
                student,
              ])
            ).values(),
          ];
          setStudents(studentsList);
          navigate("/students");
        });
      } else {
        resp.json().then((error) => setError(error.errors));
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <Container
      style={{
        marginTop: "24px",
        padding: "24px",
        border: ".5px solid grey",
        borderRadius: "8px",
        width: "75%",
      }}
    >
      <h2
        style={{
          border: ".5px solid grey",
          marginBottom: "24px",
          borderRadius: "8px",
          padding: "8px",
        }}
      >
        Assignment
      </h2>
      <Form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Name:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              name='name'
              value={assignmentData.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Subject:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              name='subject'
              value={assignmentData.subject}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row style={{ marginTop: "16px" }}>
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Notes:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as='textarea'
              name='notes'
              value={assignmentData.notes}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row style={{ marginTop: "16px" }}>
          <Col>
            <Form.Control
              type='file'
              name='file'
              multiple
              onChange={(e) =>
                setAssignmentData({ ...assignmentData, files: e.target.files })
              }
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row
          style={{
            margin: "16px",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Button type='submit' variant='success' style={{ maxWidth: "33%" }}>
            Upload
          </Button>
        </Row>
        {/* {error.map((error) => {
          return <p key={error}>{error}</p>;
        })} */}
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default AssignWork;
```

I can't get the files to send properly to the Rails backend. It either throws an error before hitting the 'byebug' or it hits the byebug but then params[:files] is nil. I also need a way to render the URL for the files when sending it back to the front end. Storage of files is currently done with ActiveStorage which stores the avatar for users.

This is the current backend code, mostly commented out as I tried to troubleshoot this:

```
def create
  byebug
  # assignment = Assignment.create!(new_assignment_params)
  # assignment.update({ files: params[:files] })
  # render json: assignment, include: "tutor.students.assignments", status: :created
end

def destroy
  assignment_to_delete = find_assignment
  if assignment_to_delete.tutor_id == @current_user.id
    assignment_to_delete.destroy
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: { error: "You do not have permission to destroy this assignment." }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end

private

def new_assignment_params
  params.permit(:name, :subject, :notes, :tutor_id, :student_id, :files)
end
```

Link to repo: https://github.com/mykovasyl/tutor-plus. I'm running Rails 6 btw!

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: ActiveStorage actually provides a javascript library that does this for you. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send files inside a JSON request. That won't ever work. You need multipart form requests to send files in their binary form. And to do that you need to be `post`ing a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, which will use the `multipart/form-data` content type (this is set automatically when using a `FormData` object with `fetch`. You can send some JSON as well with the files by adding the json as a property on the `FormData`.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const { files, ...otherAssignmentData } = assignmentData
  const formData = new FormData()

  formData.append(
    "data",
    new Blob(
      [
        JSON.stringify(otherAssignmentData),
      ],
      {
        type: "application/json",
      }
    )
  )

  for (let file in files) {
    formData.append(file.name, file)
  }

  fetch("/assignments", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }).then((resp) => {
    if (resp.ok) {
      resp.json().then((newAssignment) => {
        console.log(newAssignment)
        let studentsList = [
          ...new Map(
            newAssignment.tutor.students.map((student) => [
              student["id"],
              student,
            ])
          ).values(),
        ]
        setStudents(studentsList)
        navigate("/students")
      })
    } else {
      resp.json().then((error) => setError(error.errors))
    }
  })
}
```

Now being sent to the server is not JSON but multipart form data, which looks [something like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#content-type_in_html_forms).

There will be as many "parts" in the posted request body as there are files, plus one extra one on the "data" key for the JSON metadata.

There is more work to do on the server. Your server will need to parse the multipart form data and extract the files (which I've keyed against the filenames) and the JSON separately on the `data` key. I'm not fully familiar with ruby on rails but I think it will do this out of the box. Check the params on the incoming request.

Comment: You can actually send files in JSON (kind of) by encoding the binary data as a base64 string. This data must then be decoded on the back end. This does however increase the transmitted file size by at least 133%.

Comment: Yeh. Specifically, I meant it's the only way to send it in its original binary form. I don't think there's any reason to use "stringify and stuff in JSON" here and having to deal with a bunch of stuff handling it in userland -- when compared to the old-school multipart format.

Comment: Yeah, especially not when Rails actually includes a javascript library that handles file uploads for you.

Comment: Ah, I'm not properly familiar with Rails, but depending on the JS API (link me and I'll take a quick look) he may or may not be able to use that with React. Though it's fine as long as it doesn't interfere with actual dom rendering (totally blocked if it does) or try to hook events on DOM nodes (though that's workaroundable).

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.esm.js I think it should be relatively compatible - its designed to work with Turbo/Turbolinks which does dynamical page replacement so the event handlers are delegated.